# What is the best way to create a modular Wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm going to create a theme and I would like to create a functionality that I have seen in other themes that I have used: for example every page can be created with different modules in different order (videos, images, texts, etc...) so its up to the person creating the page to decide which elements are going to be used.

What is the best way to achieve this? I have created custom templates but I have never tried to separate the content with modules, my first guess is that it can be done using WPBakery or a similar plugin because that is what I have seen in the themes I have bought but I'm wondering if that's the best option. Do you have any recommendations or maybe a tutorial where I can see how I can accomplish this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use Advanced Custom Fields plugin and create a field with multiple possible elements. So you decide how elements will look like and the client can build his own site with that modules. The chance the client will break the layout because of superfancy layout builder is nearly zero.